# Is it possible to compress without duplication?

Tags: macos, compression

Is there a way to compress a set of files without duplicating them (i.e., I want to choose 'compress' and see the files I want compressed disappear into a zip file or other format).

I ask because I have some problem files/folders that Finder cannot delete, and I've tried tens of methods, command line, and standalone apps. I found that when compressed, Finder can delete the archive, but uncompressed, it cannot delete the files/folders, and they remain because compression programs effectively duplicate the content when they compress files/folders into a single file.

It may see a wierd way to go about solving the root problem, but it's the last shot for me. So please, answers only to my original question. Thanks

Comment: If finder can't delete them, then the archival tool probably can't delete them either.

Comment: Darth: You misunderstand. Finder can delete the folders/files when they are archived. So I want to archive without duplicating (i.e, without leaving the original files/folders and adding an archive). Am I clear? I don't need the archival tool to delete anything

Comment: You misunderstand archiving: Fundamentally, archiving creates a copy of the files. At best, the tool can opt to delete the original files after it's done copying & compressing them into the archive. If Finder can't delete the originals, then the archiver probably can't delete the originals. Finder's ability to delete the archived copy of the files doesn't really matter.

Comment: For what it's worth, this sounds a lot like a permissions issue. If you view info on the files, who owns them and what are the permissions? What about the owner/permissions on the directory that contains the files?

Comment: I understand archiving fine, which is why I'm asking the question. My question is whether there exists an archiving tool or method of using the common ones available that works on the original file INSTEAD of a duplicate. Thanks for your response.

Comment: No, because an archived file might be bigger than the original (in rare cases), so writing in-place would overwrite data that hasn't been compressed yet. Also, changing the contents of a file (compressing them) will not allow it to be deleted if the filesystem / permissions are blocking you from deleting it.

Comment: When I archive these files/folders, Finder can delete the compressed archive just fine, even though it cannot delete them uncompressed. So the compressed archive supersedes or masks any permissions issues with the original files when compressed ... Seeing this happen is why I asked my original question. Thanks.

Comment: Then have you compared file permissions/attributes before and after compressing them? *Something* must be changing if they can be deleted later. It's better to fix the actual issue rather than look for some weird workaround.

Comment: @Karan. There's something like 14,000 files in these folders, with somewhat scrambled permissions it seems, and also permissions that seem file but don't work fine. My weird workaround is because I don't have time to go through 14,000 files, have had this problem lingering for weeks, and just noticed that Finder can delete the files/folders in a compressed state. So hence my question. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to see if any of [these](http://www.lowendmac.com/misc/03/1110.html) can help.

Comment: So you're looking for a tool to open a file handle, read the contents and replace the existing contents as compressed and then change the file name of the file in place?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, deleting files after compression is achieved with something like `zip -m`, but I don't think this will be what you want. If the standard delete or rm won't work, quite likely, this won't work either -- the archiver should call the same routine to do deletion...

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I don't see the relevance. When compressed, the Finder can delete the archive of the problematic files/folders just fine. The problem is that the archive tool when creating the archive (which can be deleted) duplicates the original files/folders. I just wish it would work on the originals, because then the Finder could delete them, in a compressed form.

Comment: @Ian Compression and file permissions do not work like that at all. If Finder can't delete the file, then it doesn't matter what the contents of the file are, be they compressed or not. I assure you, it is not that Finder 'can't delete uncompressed files'; There is a permissions issue that is preventing you from deleting the files, which is why I asked you to check what the permissions were for the directory that contains the files, which I suspect you don't have write access to.

Comment: FYI, Darth, file permissions was the first thing I thought of at least 10 stages ago. Even files I have apparent Read/Write permission for are not deleting. It's not global, but restricted to 1GB of redundant files/folders on a 500GB drive

Comment: @Ian R/W on the file doesn't matter; you need write permission on the folder.